# How does python's scikit measures the 'best output' for k-means

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

Python's k-means does a given number of iterations (n_init) to find the best output of the algorithm in terms of inertia. I know how k-means works but my question is: how is the best output measured? Number of iterations needed until convergence? What is meant by terms of inertia?

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation states](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans) that the k-means algorithm is run `n_init` time and then of the results obtained it returns the one with minimum inertia:

> `n_init` : `int`, default: `10`
>
> Number of time the k-means algorithm will be run with different
>   centroid seeds. The final results will be the best output of `n_init`
>   consecutive runs in terms of inertia.

Inertia is defined in [this documentation page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means) and simply means to compute the within-cluster sum-of-squares, i.e. it means that it will return the clusters that are more compact among the one founds.

Specifically it states:

> The k-means algorithm divides a set of `N` samples `X` into `K`
>   disjoint clusters `C`, each described by the mean `μ`<sub>j</sub> of
>   the samples in the cluster. The means are commonly called the cluster
>   *centroids*; note that they are not, in general, points from `X`, although they live in the same space. The K-means algorithm aims to
>   choose centroids that minimise **the inertia, or within-cluster sum of
>   squared criterion:**
>
> ```
> ∑i=0 to n minμj ∈ C(||xj - μi||2)
> ```
>
> Inertia, or the within-cluster sum of squares criterion, can be
>   recognized as a measure of how internally coherent clusters are. It
>   suffers from various drawbacks:
>
> - Inertia makes the assumption that clusters are convex and isotropic, which is not always the case. It responds poorly to
>     elongated clusters, or manifolds with irregular shapes.
> - Inertia is not a normalized metric: we just know that lower values are better and zero is optimal. But in very high-dimensional spaces,
>     Euclidean distances tend to become inflated (this is an instance of
>     the so-called “curse of dimensionality”). Running a dimensionality
>     reduction algorithm such as PCA prior to k-means clustering can
>     alleviate this problem and speed up the computations.

Comment: Thank you so much! One additional question: "... note that they are not, in general, points from X," so this means that it is very unlikely that a centroid and a sample X are equal?

Comment: @JoaoM Yes, generally if you sample from yuor data points you wont find the centroids.